# Deleting a SharePoint subsite doesn't deletes its site columns and content types

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type, site-column, sub-site, site-deletion

I have a subsites inside a site collection. There I have defined some custom content types. Once I deleted the subsite, and created a new subsite with the same name and url, I can see all the old content types already there. Is this a normal behavior? How can I deleted it completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct behavior. Columns are defined at the site collection level or list level so deleting a subsite will not delete them unless they were defined as list columns.

You need to go to site settings on the parent site collection --> Site columns and then delete them from there.